# Jekyll: kramdown ignoring input in _config.yml

Tags: jekyll, syntax-highlighting, kramdown, rouge

I am trying to make syntax highlighting on my jekyll site work with the syntax for syntax highlighting that is also supported by github. Currently, I use this syntax to highlight my code:

```
{% highlight css %}
/* code */
{% endhighlight %}
```

Which does work fine on my site, but is not working on github. Instead, I need it to work with this supported syntax:

```
´´´ css
/* code */
´´´
```

It is a requirement that the syntax is also being highlighted on github. So I found this [blogpost](https://sacha.me/articles/jekyll-rouge/) and followed it along. But it is not working. I don't get any errors, this part is just not interpreted by kramdown and is instead just turned into a `<p>`.

I tried installing an older version of jekyll 3.0 which also did not make any difference. I googled the problem and found many people having the same issues, but they got turned down rather fiercely by the people on github which is the reason why I am asking the question here instead of opening an issue on github. They say that this is a known bug resolved in [3.1](https://jekyllrb.com/news/2016/02/19/jekyll-3-1-2-released/), but I have 3.1.2 and it is not resolved for me.

I have also installed the rouge and kramdown gems (1.10.1 and 1.10). I believe, that jekyll just straight up ignores these settings in my `_config.yml`:

```
markdown: kramdown

kramdown:
  input: GFM
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
```

If anyone could maybe help on this, that would be great.

Comment: That sounds strange. I advise you to add a `Gemfile` file with the following content `gem 'github-pages'` and run `bundle install`. Now you should have the same gems as on Github Pages and see if it works.

Comment: I should have also added, that I already installed the github-pages gem, which installed the 3.0.3 version of jekyll. That also did not help.

Comment: Well, the first syntax is the one for Pygments, so my hunch is that you may have messed up your gems. Can you run `bundle exec jekyll serve` just to be sure jekyll runs with the correct gems? Or can you isolate those gems in a fresh environment using `rvm` or `rbenv`?

Comment: Installing bundler and executing `bundle exec jekyll serve` tells me `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`. Im just a Frontend Designer and I know just enough to get my tools working with the commandline, so I have unfortunately no idea what you mean by > can you isolate those gems in a fresh environment using rvm or rbenv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `ACUTE ACCENT &#180;` instead of `GRAVE ACCENT &#96;`

Replace

```
´´´ css
/* code */
´´´
```

by

````
``` css
/* code */
```
````